# Getting error "Array is Fixed or Locked" when splitting string

Tags: arrays, vbscript, split

I have this issue with my vbscript file. It actually read data from first file and use it to compare with values in second file. If there is a match necessary things are done. This code is working fine for the first value from the first file. But for second input error appears as that this array is fixed or temporary locked. I searched in internet and found the issue is with the fixed size of array and can be solved by redim function. I don't know it is the correct solution or not. Here is the complete code. Thanks in advance.

```
    set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set shell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    set file =fs.OpenTextFile("C:\wamp\www\order.csv",1,false)'Read from orders.csv (Current Orders)
    set output =fs.OpenTextFile("C:\wamp\www\completed-orders.csv",8)'Output file. All Completed     Order's Number are placed here
    Set tempfile = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\wamp\www\temp-order.csv",true) 'Create temporary text files to store the line numbers to be deleted

    set p=fs.OpenTextFile("C:\wamp\www\current.csv",1,false)'Read the path to the current Stock Data File
    path=p.ReadLine
    p.close()
    path = Trim(path)
    set n=fs.OpenTextFile(path,1,false)'Read the data from it and check for name match and then whether current price is >= order price.
    line=0
    'format of line in order.csv written from php        'fwrite($file,$company."||".$price."||".$oid."||".$type."||".$email
    do while file.AtEndOfStream<>true
    lin=file.ReadLine
    Wscript.Echo line
    Wscript.Echo lin
    if lin="" Then
       noerr=false
    else
       noerr=true
    end if
    Wscript.Echo noerr & " error variable"
    if noerr Then
          temp=Split(lin,"||") 'Read the first order (id,price)
          i=0
          for each data in temp
          If i=0 Then
             namestock=data
          ElseIf i=1 Then
             target=CDbl(data)
          ElseIf i=2 Then
             orderid=data
          ElseIf i=3 Then
             buysell=data
          ElseIf i=4 Then
             transtype=data
          ElseIf i=5 Then
             emailto=data
          ElseIf i=6 Then 'Bharti Airtel ||300.90||100000004||BUY||INTR||email@hotmail.com||5||1506.45585 format of lin
          nos=CInt(data)
          Else
            totalprice=CDbl(data)
          End If
          i=i+1

          next
     do while n.AtEndOfStream <>true 'Compare against current data
        stock=Split(n.ReadLIne,"||")
        j=0
        for each name in stock
            If j=0 Then
                If StrComp(namestock,name,1)=0 Then
                   Wscript.Echo namestock & "  name matched"
                   check = true
                   j=j+1
                Else
                   Exit For
                End If
             Else If j=1 Then
                If buysell="BUY" Then
                        If CDbl(name) <=target Then
                        tempfile.WriteLine(line) 'Add the line to temporary file if condition is satisfied.
                        output.WriteLine(orderid)  'Write orderno to complete-orders
                        shell.run "send.vbs 1 "& emailto &" "& target &" "& buysell &" "& transtype &" "& nos &" "&totalprice &" "& namestock & " Order Completed"
                        Wscript.Echo "sended"
                End If  
                ElseIf buysell="SELL" Then
                    If CDbl(name) >=target Then
                        tempfile.WriteLine(line) 'Add the line to temporary file if condition is satisfied.
                        output.WriteLine(orderid)  'Write orderno to complete-orders
                        shell.run "send.vbs 1 "& emailto &" "& target &" "& buysell &" "& transtype &" "& nos &" "&totalprice &" "& namestock & " Order Completed"
                    End If  
                End If
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    next
loop
end if
line=line+1

loop
n.close()
tempfile.close()
file.close()
output.close()
```

This is part of my miniproject. A simple stock market system. This piece of code is to be used for order is to be accepted or not by the system. It does the intended works fine for the first line, but for second line from the order.csv, but it will not work due to the error occurring on the stock variable.

Comment: There just isn't enough content or explanation to answer this question.

Comment: Sorry for not adding necessary code.I have added the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole approach is flawed. You try to read `all` lines from `n` for `each` line from `file`. That won't work without opening (and closing) `n` each time.

You should edit your question to disclose your real world problem/what you want to achieve with some sample data. Then it may be possible to give you useful advice.